# Launch VLC through Python

Tags: python, vlc

To start vlc using python, I've done that :

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["C:\Program Files(x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe","C:\Users\Kamilos\Desktop\TBT\Tbt_S01E17.avi"])
```

But it doesn't work, why ? :p

(tested in python 2.7.3 and 3)

EDIT SOLVED : like Drake said, just replace back-slash with blash

```
subprocess.Popen(["C:/Program Files(x86)/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe","C:/Users/Kamilos/Desktop/TBT/Tbt_S01E17.avi"])‌​
```

Comment: `p = subprocess.Popen([r"C:\Program Files(x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe",r"C:\Users\Kamilos\Desktop\TBT\Tbt_S01E17.avi"])`

Comment: Thanks for help but it doesn't work neither, I've got always the same error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kamilos\Desktop\site.py", line 2, in <module>
    Popen(["C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"])
  File "C:\Python32\lib\subprocess.py", line 736, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\subprocess.py", line 946, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] Le fichier spécifié est introuvable (The file cannot be found)

Comment: Try replace back-slash with blash. Ex, **subprocess.Popen(["C:/Program Files(x86)/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe","C:/Users/Kamilos/Desktop/TBT/Tbt_S01E17.avi"])**

Comment: @LolPallau: To mark a question as solved, click the check mark outline beside one of the answers. You'll have to get Drake to post his comment as an answer if you want to accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are effectively escaping every character after the path separator. In the same way that `"\n"` means a new line, `"\P"`, `"\V"` also mean something other than just a 2-character string.

You could just use `"\\"` (or `"/"`, can't remember which Windows uses) for the path separator, but the proper way is to get Python to join the path together for you using [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

Try:

```
import subprocess
import os

p = subprocess.Popen([os.path.join("C:/", "Program Files(x86)", "VideoLAN", "VLC", "vlc.exe"),os.path.join("C:/", "Users", "Kamilos", "Desktop", "TBT", "Tbt_S01E17.avi")])
```

Comment: Better use 'C:\\' instead of 'C:/' as the result of 'C:\' will be 'C:/Program...)\...\...\vlc.exe' (note the wrong slash) while using '\\' will result correctly 'C:\Program Files(x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe'. both worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Verify that the path exists:

```
import os
print os.path.exists("C:\Users\Kamilos\Desktop\TBT\Tbt_S01E17.avi")
```

Answer (score -2):

It worked this way for me:

```
os.system(''start vlc C:\\local\\file\\name.mp4")
```

or:

```
subprocess.Popen(["C:/Program Files (x86)/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe","C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Desktop\\videos\\example.mp4"])
```

-the difference is in the way to put the: ' \ ' , ' // '